# Why is my Python code doing a sys.exit after I choose my option

Tags: python, input

The Code.
 if I enter `a/b/c/q` it defaults to `sys.exit`

I've got literally no idea why it does this, so any suggestions are really welcome.

```
import sys
print('             Option A             ')
print('             Option B             ')
print('             Option C             ')
answer = input(' ').lower

if answer == 'a':

#code is here
sys.exit

if answer == 'b':

#more code is here
sys.exit

elif answer == 'c':

#more code here
sys.exit


elif answer == 'q':
print ("exit program')
sys.exit
```

Any help would be amazing! (I'm fairly new to python, version 3.5.1)

Comment: Your indentation is off, but it looks like you've got `sys.exit` everywhere - although you're never actually calling it, either. I'm not sure what's going on in your code.

Comment: it should probably be sys.exit() if you actually want to exit.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the indentation:

```
if answer == 'a':

#code is here
sys.exit
```

Should be:

```
if answer == 'a':
  #code is here
  sys.exit()
```

You'll need to do this for your other `if` and `elif` as well.

Note that the addition of the `()` since `exit` is a function, not an attribute of `sys`.